# Recommending someone to my company during the notice period

Tags: ethics, notice-period, referral

I'm currently serving my notice period in a company I've been working at for a few years now, and there's a few more weeks to go. My company is a large corporation with offices all around the world.

A friend of mine (who I believe is qualified for the job) asked me to refer him to a position in one of our offices in our home country, where he currently resides, and I have no problem doing so. The role is not related to my work, and he will not be a replacement for me; it's an unrelated department.

The question is: Are there any potential red flags or negative repercussions on that friend if I refer him a few weeks before leaving myself? How should I approach the situation? I don't care about any referral bonus. I do not know the manager I am referring him to, since he works in a different country and we haven't interacted previously.

Comment: Did you resign of your own will, or were you asked to resign or dismissed?

Comment: I have to disagree with the close votes, as stating potential pitfalls and considerations is quite objective thing.

Answer (score 4):

As long as there is no bad blood between you and the company, go ahead and recommend your friend. As long as your reputation within the company is good, that should help your friend.